# Googledrive app for windowsphone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, google-drive-api

I am developing a Google Drive application for Windows Phone using URLs provided in the SDK through HTTPWebRequest. Is there an API for WP8 to develop Google Drive applications?

I downloaded all of the content without any problem. While I am uploading the MIMEtype, it is not always uploaded correctly, and is uploaded as an octet stream.

Please can anyone help with how to upload to Google Drive using C# code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution, actually i am using  string[] HeaderKeys = { "X-Upload-Content-Type" }; string[] HeaderValues = { "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" } for post method,
here i used request.contentType in the place of X-Upload-Content-Type now i am uploading all files with correct stream.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Upload Files" section of the Google Drive SDK :

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Comment: Hi i take help from this document and develop and i uploaded correctly, till two days back it works good and uploaded correct mimetype,now from two days the same code i am running agian i found that uploaded mimetype is octetstream only...is it depends on client id,secret or key???

Comment: take an example of creating folder in gdrive for this i am doing in two steps first one to create folder using post request and second to update name and mimetype by put request

Comment: first method post  string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media&access_token=" + Goolgletoken;                 string[] HeaderKeys = { "X-Upload-Content-Type" };
            string[] HeaderValues = { "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" };

Comment: second put  string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + id + "?&access_token=" + Goolgletoken;
            String multipartRequestBody = "{\"title\":\"" + FolderName + "\", \"mimeType\": \"application/vnd.google-apps.folder\"}";

Comment: url is Upload url and HeaderKeys is header and HeaderValues is value and multipartRequestBody is body

Comment: what i am wondering is before two days it worked properly from last two days it is not working i.e,mimetype is always as OctetStream not as application/vnd.google-apps.folder,name is updating mime not...

Comment: if u dont understand please provide me an exmaple to create folder in googledrive using webrequest

Comment: hi catalin Manoliu, can u tell how to upload through webrequest